# JavaScript - testing implementation of NodeJS readline.createInterface using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, command-line-interface, readline

I'm building a command-line application in NodeJS and I want to thoroughly test it using Jasmine.

I've implemented a `promptUser()` method which uses Node's `readline.createInterface` method to pose a question and pipe the response into a callback. I want to test that, given a user response of '`q`', my module's `quit()` function is called.

However I'm struggling to test this. I don't really want to test the `readline` method directly, since I didn't write that code, but I reasoned that if I can create a listener on `process.stdout.write` then when `enter command:` is printed to the screen I can respond with `process.stdin.write("q\n")` and trigger the if/else logic.

I've simplified the code, but should explain what I'm trying to do:

Module source code:

```
var Cli = function() {

  var rl = require('readline');
  var self = this;

  Cli.prototype.promptUser = function() {
    var inputHandler = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
    inputHandler.question('enter command: ', function(answer) {
      if (answer === 'q') {
        self.quit();
      };
    });
  };

  Cli.prototype.quit = function() {
    // doSomething
  };
};

module.exports = Cli;
```

Jasmine test:

```
var Cli = require('Cli');

describe('My application.', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    cli = new Cli();
    spyOn(cli, 'quit');
  });

  describe('Cli #promptUser', function() {
    it('input of lower-case q calls cli.quit()', function() {  
      process.stdout.once('write', function() {
        process.stdin.write("q\n");
      });
      cli.promptUser();
      expect(cli.quit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

I'm looking to either make this approach work or find a better way to test my code. I suspect there is probably a superior/more direct approach.

Comment: you probably figured this out but you can use `rl.write(message + '\n\r')`

Comment: Thanks @vbranden. I don't think I did figure this out, and I never came back to it - but I appreciate the response. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.